# Korean partner studying the in the US, I want to move with her

Tags: usa, visa

I don't know what to do but distance and lack of visa is keeping me away from my loved one.

I am a venezuelan resident with no other nationality, I met her quite a while ag and we have had a long distance relationship because she is studying in the US, and she wants to stay there after finishing her studies.

Marrying is not an option as she is just a student with a student visa.

I don't even have an American visa because last time it was rejected. That was about 4 years ago, so I am trying again but because the Venezuelan government sent home most of the workers from the US embassy, it takes a long time to even get an appointment (I just received the date for mine and it is 8 months from now) and that is only for a tourist visa.

What are my chances and options of actually going the US and live with her?

ps: I don't have the money for investing (unfortunate venezuelan exchange)

I would love to go and find a job anywhere in the US before I can move with her.

Answer (score 3):

If you're married you can get a "dependent" visa of whatever status she's on (F2 if she's on F1 or J2 if she's on J1). Your status will be directly tied to her, and in case of J2 - you'll be able to work.

If marrying is not an option then you're out of options, tell you the truth. Theoretically, there's a "partner" visa, a semi-official way for unmarried partners to get an extended stay on a regular B2 tourist visa. But given your background and the fact that the relationship is mainly long-distance - I suspect that the visa officer would not believe you.

In any case, even if you get that option - you won't be able to work and you and your partner (who is also not allowed to work) will need to figure out how to support yourself. Which is another reason for your visa application to likely be rejected even if the VO does believe you.

Comment: We have have met during her vacations and there is proof but anyways even if we marry in some other country that wouldn't give me the chance to get a visa or would it?

Comment: @Granola if you're married you can get a "dependent" visa of whatever status she's on (F2 if she's on F1 or J2 if she's on J1). Your status will be directly tied to her, and in case of J2 - you'll be able to work.